# How to apply label to strip based on symbol present in two parallel array

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I have data strips of length 3600. This data strip has two values.

1. symbols
2. aux_note
   it looks like this - https://extendsclass.com/csv-editor.html#031e1f1

If the aux note is empty, it means consider the previous aux note value.

Above data frame is of length 100000+, I want to create strip(window) of 3600 lengths.

I apply set on each strip to get the unique symbols and aux_note for each strip. 1st array contains symbols, another array contains aux_note.

Symbol value we get every time, but the aux_note value we get only if there is some event. If the aux_note value is empty that means it considers previous aux_note values ( previous event state )

Two array looks like this. When we apply `set` operation on each strip, it give symbol and aux_note as below.

```
sym_list = set(strip['symbol'])
aux_note_list = set(strip['aux_note'])
print(sym_list, cur_aux_note)

{'+', 'V', 'N'} {'', '(N\x00'}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'V', 'N'} {''}
{'V', 'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'V', 'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'A', 'N'} {''}
{'V', 'N'} {''}
{'V', 'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'V', 'N'} {''}
{'V', 'N'} {''}
{'|', 'V', 'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'A', 'a', 'N'} {''}
{'V', 'A', 'a', 'N'} {''}
{'A', 'N'} {''}
{'|', 'N'} {''}
{'N', 'A'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'A', 'a', 'N'} {''}
{'+', 'A', 'a', 'N'} {'', '(AFIB\x00', '(N\x00'}
{'+', 'A', 'a', 'N'} {'', '(AFIB\x00'}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'V', 'N'} {''}
{'+', 'F', 'A', 'N'} {'', '(AFIB\x00', '(N\x00'}
{'a', 'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'+', 'N'} {'', '(AFL'}
{'N'} {''}
{'+', 'V', 'N'} {'', '(AFIB'}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'a', 'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
{'N'} {''}
```

I want to give a label to each strip based on the value present in the strip symbol and aux_note. Aux_note is the decision maker here.

1. If aux note and symbol are the same, give the strip's label as aux_note. eg { N } { N } then label = N
2. If Aux note is value other than N, and that value present in symbols, then give aux note values as label. eg. {A,N}{A} then label = A
3. Give highest priority to A, eg. {A,V,N}{A} then label = A

My attempt

```
for i in range(num_strips):
    strp = {}
    strp['signal'] = df_data[i * len_ecg_strip : (i+1)*len_ecg_strip]['MLII']

    
    temp = df_descr[df_descr['sample'] >= i * len_ecg_strip]
    temp = temp[df_descr['sample'] <= (i+1)*len_ecg_strip]
    
    strp['sample'] = temp['sample']
    strp['symbol'] = temp['symbol']
    strp['aux_note'] = temp['aux_note']
    prev_aux_note = strip_validate(strp, prev_aux_note)

def strip_validate(strip, pre_aux):
    sym_list = set(strip['symbol'])
    aux_note_list = list(set(strip['aux_note']))
    aux_note_list = list(filter(None,aux_note_list))
    pdb.set_trace()
    if len(aux_note_list)==0:
        cur_aux_note = pre_aux
        label = cur_aux_note
    elif len(aux_note_list) == 1:
        cur_aux_note = aux_note_list[0]
        label = cur_aux_note
    elif 'AFIB' in aux_note_list:
        cur_aux_note = 'AFIB'
        label = cur_aux_note
    else:
        cur_aux_note = aux_note_list[1]
        label = cur_aux_note
       
    print(sym_list, cur_aux_note)
    return cur_aux_note, label
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Comment: @ScottHunter: I edited with my attempt

Comment: Where/how is this attempting to do any of #1, #2 or #3, and how is it coming up short?

Comment: @ScottHunter:  That I suppose to do in  `strip_validate ` but struggling with it.

Comment: How is it *attempting* to do it?